# what is the advantage of imageNamed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caching, uiimage

I know that loading an image like this

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
```

will cache the image and loading it like this will not

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"img.png"];
```

people say the it will be faster to access the cached image because iOS will access it from memory and we will not have the overhead of reading and decoding the file. OK, I see that, but suppose I use the second non-cached method to load the image on a view that is a property, like this

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"img.png"];
  self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

isn't image already on memory? If I want to access it I simply do imageView.image and get it from memory.

I am probably tired but I cannot imagine a single use for the cached version or I am not understanding what this cache means.

Care to explain? Thanks.

Comment: Cache and memory both are two different concepts. Say like, when you use imageNamed, it'll first look in the cache, if it's there it'll be loaded else will load from disk. When you use imageWithContentsOfFile: it'll load the image directly from disk.

Comment: Think if your imageView is on firstView and you are calling imageWithContentsOfFile, how can it access imageView of first view and take the image ?

Comment: if you only access/load the image once you get no benefit from `imageNamed:`, actually in that case you should use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, the benefit of using `imageNamed:` is when you use the same image from multiple places

Comment: If you need the image several times during the run of the app, then use a cache...

Comment: so, what you are saying is that I can only save the image to a property if it is cached? I don't think so.

Comment: I think you guys are not understanding the question. Cached or not, I can save the image to a property and access it everywhere, including passing to other view controllers. You will have to come with a better answer 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that your image is some icon that you use in 7 different view controllers... You could either load the image once and then pass it to each VC or you could use `imageNamed`... Your choice.

Comment: Your explanation is not good. I can pass an image to another viewController even if is not cached.

Comment: I said that in my explanation. You could do that, but you don't have to because you could use `imageNamed` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. The cache is a box with images and tags, it is not attached to anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:):

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or asset catelog, and then returns the resulting object. You can not assume that this method is thread safe.

Let's say you have an image in your app.  When you need to use the image, you use this code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"img.png"];
```

iOS will then look for your image in the app bundle, load it into memory, and then decode it into the UIImage.

However, say you need 10 different objects to use the image and you load it similar to this:

```
for (ClassThatNeedsImage *object in objects) {
    object.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"img.png"];
}
```

(This isn't the best example since you could just load the image once and pass it to each of the objects.  However, I have had more complex code where that is not an option.)

iOS will then look for the image 10 times, load it into memory 10 times, and then decode it 10 times.  However, if you use imageNamed:

```
for (ClassThatNeedsImage *object in objects) {
    object.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
}
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)):

> In computing, a cache is a component that transparently stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster.

The cache used by `UIImage` is stored in memory, which is much faster to access than the disk.

The first time through the loop, iOS looks in the cache to see if the image is stored there.  Assuming you haven't loaded this image with `imageNamed` previously, it doesn't find it, so it looks for the image, loads it into memory, decodes it, and then copies it into the cache.

On the other iterations, iOS looks in the cache, finds the image, and copies it into the UIImage object, so it doesn't have to do any hard disk access at all.

---

If you are only going to use the image once in the lifetime of your app, use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.  If you are going to use the image multiple times, use `imageNamed:`.